# How do I convert Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM to 9999-12-31T00:00:00 in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

How do I convert "Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM" to "9999-12-31T00:00:00" in SQLite database.

It would also be sufficient if someone could help me covert "Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM" to just '9999-12-31' as well. I can then use the following:

select STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', '9999-12-31') as ExpiryDate

Thank you in advance.

Here's how I could do it in Python. I wanted to know if we could do the same in SQLite directly.

```
>>> d = 'Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM'
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0)
>>> d2 = d1.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
>>> d2
'9999-12-31T00:00:00'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a built-in inverse to its `STRFTIME` function.  You can create a user-defined function for it, though.

```
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(FILENAME)
>>> db.create_function('strptime', 2, lambda s, f: str(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, f)))
>>> list(db.execute("SELECT STRPTIME('2020-02-24 17:47:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"))
[('2020-02-24 17:47:00',)]
>>> list(db.execute("SELECT STRPTIME('Dec 31, 9999 12:00:00 AM', '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')"))
[('9999-12-31 00:00:00',)]
```